# How do I replace a certain string in a list from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I made a list which contains a number of names and a menu with options that the user can use to alter the list. One of the options is to replace one of the names in the list with whatever the user inputs. How can this be done? I prefer to not use indexes

My code so far:

```
print("==================")
names = ["Chris", "Dave", "Joseph", "Harvey", "Levi"]
print(names)
print("==================")

print("(A) Add a name \n(B) Change a name \n(C) Delete a name \n(D) View all names \n(Q) Quit ")
print("==================")

while True:

    choice = input("Select an option: ").lower()

    if choice == "a":
        newName = input("Enter a new name: ")
        names.append(newName)

    elif choice == "b":
        oldName = input("What name would you like to replace?: ")
        newName = input("Enter a new name: ")

        # I don't know what to put here
    

    elif choice == "c":
        delete = input("Which name do you want to remove?: ")
        names.remove(delete)

    elif choice == "d":
        print(names)

    elif choice == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: You should just use the index. But if you really don't want to, since you know how to add a name and delete a name, why not delete the old name and add the replacement?

Comment: Also agree with @MarkMeyer, you should also consider handling if the user is not present in the list. Same for ```choice == "c"``` else your code will fail with an exception being raised

Comment: @ Mark Meyer @ Nic Laforge I prefer that the replaced name is in the exact position as the old name, but don't worry @coderoftheday told me I can use list compression instead

Comment: @wasd237 if my answer has worked, you can give it a tick

Comment: @coderoftheday Ahh ok, I'll do that

Comment: @wasd237 you didn't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really would be a good idea to use index here, and you can look up the specific index at the time the user looks it up.

```
elif choice == "b":
    oldName = input("What name would you like to replace?: ")
    newName = input("Enter a new name: ")

    i = names.index(oldName)
    names[i] = newName
```

It would also be useful to add validation to make sure that the app doesn't crash when a name is entered that isn't in the list. Something like:

```
if oldName in names:
    i = names.index(oldName)
    names[i] = newName
else:
    print("That name is not in the list")
```

The same validation could be added to the delete option.

Answer (score 0):

```
    elif choice == "b":
        oldName = input("What name would you like to replace?: ")
        newName = input("Enter a new name: ")
        names = [x if x != oldName else newName for x in names ]
        print(names)
```

You can use a list comprehension to add the names if the name does not equal `oldName`, if the name does equal `oldName` then add the `newName` instead.